# yum install older version docker

Tags: docker, centos, yum

I'm using centos7. And a few months ago I install docker 1.12 by running `docker install dokcer`. Recently, I still use this command and I get docker  1.13. I found yum update extra repo with dokcer 1.13. However I need dokcer 1.12. How can I install the older version 1.12 with yum extra repo? Is there any archive repo I can use ? I don't want to install docker 1.12 through docker's repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!

```
yum -y update
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7
yum -y update
yum -y --nogpgcheck install docker-engine-1.12.6-1.el7.centos.x86_64
service docker start
```

Comment: Is there a way to install the centos version of docker instead of dockerproject ?